# Memory Concerns with Caching and Updating Data In Asp.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have created a C# Asp.NET web application that utilizes the application cache and WebSockets. When the first request comes in from a client that connects to the WebSocket to retrieve data, the code in the Global.asax Application_BeginRequest method does the following to kick things off:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e){
    List<object> objectList = this.Application["NameOfObjectList"] as List<object>;

    if (objectList != null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // create the list
    objectList = new List<object>();

    // add list to application cache so it can be used later by an async method
    this.Application.Add("NameOfObjectList", objectList);
}
```

In a later async method that is the callback of an continuously awaited UDP socket connection, that method does the following:

```
private async Task DecodeData(byte[] udpDatagramData){
    // get a copy of the current list of objects from application cache
    List<object> objectList = (List<object>)this.Application["NameOfObjectList"];

    // decode the udp datagram data and convert it into a object

    /* if object list length is greater than set threshold, remove first object */
    if (objectList.Count > ObjectCacheLimit)
    {
        objectList.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    // add new object to end of list
    objectList.Add(object);

    // broadcast the object to all WebSocket connected clients
    WebSocket.Send(ResponseSerializer.Serialize(object));

    // re-cache the object list back into memory
    this.Application["NameOfObjectList] = objectList;
}
```

The main reason I am storing data in cache is so that when new clients connect in via the WebSocket, they can pull down a copy of the current data in memory to their machine to do something with. Therefore, my question simply is this...

Are there issues or concerns with possible memory leaks when pulling/pushing data in/out of the application cache this way? I'm not sure if this is an ineffective or harmful way to be caching and updating data in memory.

Comment: If you want to cache data, why don't use you use the [inbuilt cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx)? Note if you really want to use the Application object then you should consider using [Locking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525184(v=vs.90).aspx) - as that page says _"If one page tries to edit the application collection without locking and a second page also tries to edit the collection, no error is sent by IIS and the Application object ends up in an inconsistent state."_

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I switched over to using the inbuilt cache and it behaves just a well as the other method.